# Loop issues. A list of Prime Numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, variables, loops

I know everything is extremely wrong. What I'm trying to do is create a list of Prime numbers, up to and including the given number. Please try to explain simply. I'm new to this. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

'Author: Murray Spears
'Date: October 5th 2012

'Creating a Program that will ask the user for a number. 
'The program will then generate prime numbers up to and including the number entered by the user.

Imports System

Module PrimeNumbers

    Sub Main()

        Dim Number As Integer
        Dim One As Integer = 1
        Dim Prime As Boolean


        'Ask the user for their chosen number.
        Console.Writeline("Choose a number:")
        Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline())
        ' We have to let the program know that we only want numbers that are divisible by one and themselves, up to the entered value.

        Do While Number <= Number
        Loop

        Do While Number / One = Number
        Loop

        Do While Number / Prime = Number
        Loop

        Console.Out.Writeline("Here are the prime numbers:")
        Console.Out.Writeline(Number)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: My bad, I screwed up a reformatting edit. Fixed now. Not the OP's fault.

Comment: This may sound harsh (not intentional) but you should read on setting and using variables and operators. You have a bunch of loops but you do nothing in them so nothing happens.

Comment: I'm not sure you're struggling with code here... it looks more like you are struggling with maths... I would suggest you do what Heinzi recommends.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Do While Number <= Number
Loop
```

is an endless loop since `Number <= Number` is *always* true.

A general hint: Stop coding. Take a piece of paper and try to write down the *algorithm* you want to use (in plain English), i.e., the steps you want the computer to take. Do this, until you are convinced that this will give you the desired result.

Once you have worked out your algorithm, try to implement it in code. If you have trouble with that, come back here, post your algorithm and explain which problems you are having with implementing it.